# MVVM & Binding & Context

Tags: android, mvvm, binding

My colleague and I had an argument.
We are translating the application to MVVM+Binding.
There was a need to start a dialog from a fragment.
I do it like this:

In the fragment:

```
fragmentBinding.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       // there's a bunch of code here 
     alertDialog.show();
}});
```

A colleague also claims that you need to do this:

In the xml file we write as follows:

```
android:onClick="@{v -> viewModel.showDialog(context)}"
```

And in the ViewModel:

```
fun showDialog(context: Context){
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       // there's a bunch of code here
     alertDialog.show();
}
```

Please, tell me, which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewModel is responsible for preparing data for the UI, as mentioned in the [Android Developer Guides](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Therefore one best practice is never to deal with UI elements in ViewModel. Although the codes will still execute if we pass the `Context` to the ViewModel and allow it to show an `alertDialog`, you may also need to be aware that the activity/fragment and the ViewModel have different lifecycles, so you need to be careful when passing the `Context` to the ViewModel

A more sensible way to handle this, would be for the ViewModel to maintain a flag and prepare the required message using `LiveData` or something similar, so that the activity / fragment observes that and actually build and show an `AlertDialog` by getting the message from the ViewModel, and notify the ViewModel when the dialog has been shown/clicked, so that the ViewModel will handle the subsequent business logic.

For your particular case, I would leave the `AlertDialog` code in the activity/fragment, while if necessary I will retrieve the data from the ViewModel.